# Uniting Columns in an R data frame that have same suffix

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I am trying to unite columns based on the same suffix to get from a table like this:

```
| Forename_1 | Surname_1 | Forename_2 | Surname_2 |
| Joe        | Bloggs    | Dave       | Jones     |
```

to this:

```
| Fullname_1 | Fullname_2 |
| Joe Bloggs | Dave Jones |
```

What can I do to get there?
I know I need to use the *unite()* function but I am unsure of the syntax to use to identify the string and complete the operation based on that.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to keep the names separated?

Typically when I have issues like this I combine all data of the same type into a single column. In your case that would be Forename and Surname.

Comment: In this situation this might be best accomplished through a pivot_longer. initially extracting the forename columns and then the surname columns.  If you need to keep the integer value this will be available in the names_to column.

Answer (score 1):

One way would to get data in long format getting the suffix in separate column. We can combine the values for each suffix and get data in wide format again.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_sep = "_", 
               names_to = c("type", "suffix")) %>%
  summarise(value = paste(value, collapse = " "), .by = suffix) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = suffix, names_prefix = "Fullname_")

# Fullname_1 Fullname_2
#  <chr>      <chr>     
#1 Joe Bloggs Dave Jones
```

**data**

It is easier to help if you provide data in a [reproducible format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

```
df <- structure(list(Forename_1 = "Joe", Surname_1 = "Bloggs", 
     Forename_2 = "Dave", Surname_2 = "Jones"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), 
     class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak, I get this error on running the above:

Error in `chr_as_locations()`:
! Can't subset columns past the end.
x Column `suffix` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

A base R option with `split.default`

```
list2DF(
    lapply(
        split.default(df, sub(".*_", "Fullname_", names(df))),
        paste0,
        collapse = " "
    )
)
```

## Data

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(Forename_1 = "Joe", Surname_1 = "Bloggs", Forename_2 = "Dave",
    Surname_2 = "Jones"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = "data.frame")
```

gives

```
  Fullname_1 Fullname_2
1 Joe Bloggs Dave Jones
```